# Правильно ли заданы конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания? Как улучшить?

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток. Продолжаю своё путешествие по классам и их аспектам. В этот раз наткнулся на конструкторы копирования и операторы присваивания.

Из matrix.h:

```
Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& matr);//Оператор присваивания
Matrix(const Matrix &matr); //Конструктор копирования
```

Из matrix.cpp:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &matr){//Конструктор копирования

m_rows = matr.m_rows;
m_cols = matr.m_cols;

m_matrix = new int*[m_rows];
for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++)
    m_matrix[i] = new int[m_cols];

for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m_cols; j++)
        m_matrix[i][j] = matr.m_matrix[i][j];

}

Matrix& Matrix::operator = (const Matrix& matr){//Оператор присваивания

if (&matr == this){
}else{

    m_rows = matr.m_rows;
    m_cols = matr.m_cols;

    m_matrix = new int*[m_rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++)
        m_matrix[i] = new int[m_cols];

    for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m_cols; j++)
            m_matrix[i][j] = matr.m_matrix[i][j];

}
return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если в конструкторе копирования все более-менее нормально, то в присваивании - у вас нет освобождения уже занятой памяти, так что как минимум вы получаете утечку.

Я бы рекомендовал использовать идиому обмена. Смотрите, пишем закрытую функцию обмена

```
void Matrix::swap(Matrix&m)
{
    std::swap(m_rows,m.m_rows);
    std::swap(m_cols,m.m_cols);
    std::swap(m_matrix,m.m_matrix);
}
```

а дальше пусть за нас работает эта функция и конструктор копировнаия - зачем нам дублировать такой длинный код?

```
Matrix& operator = (const Matrix& m)
{
    if (this == &m) return *this; // Но будет работать даже без этого!
    Matrix tmp(m); // копирование
    swap(tmp);     // обмен, теперь наша матрица - копия
    return *this;  // удаление выполнится деструктором tmp автоматически
}
```

Comment: Если обмен между переменными m_rows и m_cols при помощи свапа понятен(ибо это обычные инты), то как swap обрабатывает двойные указатели? Также как и другие стандартные типы данных? 
Если не затруднит, то можно краткое описание std::swap? Как именно он обрабатывает любые типы данных при обмене?

Comment: Тут нужен именно обмен значений переменных. Если сомневаетесь - напишите сами:  `int**tmp = m_matrix; m_matrix = m.m_matrix; m.m_matrix = tmp;` Вот как работает стандартный `swap`: http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap

Comment: Встречал разные комментарии на эту тему. Некоторые советуют не просто копировать указатели, а выделять под них новую память(собственно как и сделано в конструкторе копирования), а в других достаточно и просто скопировать указатель на данные. То есть, по сути, создать ещё один указатель, указывающий на тоже самое. 
Разумеется, что-то я понимаю ещё не верно, но есть ощущение, что во взаимодействии указателей где-то может возникнуть ошибка.
Да, референс тоже смотрел, но на http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/ . Увидел использование ещё одного стандартного метода move и остановился

Comment: Вдумайтесь в то, что делает оператор присваивания. Сначала он должен сделать то, что делает деструктор - освободить память. Потом то, что делает конструктор копирования - выделить память и скопировать значения. Зачем нам писать этот код еще раз? При наличии **очень дешевой** функции обмена мы просто 1. делаем копию. 2. Обмениваем ее с нашим объектом. Теперь все внутренние поля нашего объекта такие, как должны быть, а временный объект содержит поля, которые были в нашем объекте. И которые при выходе будут уничтожены - **автоматическим** вызовом деструктора. Никакого повтора кода.

Comment: Единственный минус - что сначала создается копия, а уничтожение (освобождение памяти) делается потом. Но в этом есть и плюс: наш объект не может оказаться в несогласованном состоянии из-за какого-то исключения, например. Словом, еще раз подумайте, насколько это выгоднее :) Представьте, что вы меняете копирование каким-то образом. А присваивание - заметим - при этом перписывать не надо... В то время как при вашем подходе надо поддерживать две копии копирования и две копии освобождения памяти. И зачем? просто из непонимания? :)

Comment: Ну так затем и обращаюсь к знающим людям, чтобы получать комментарии и запоминать более эффективные методы, а затем и понимать их в будущей перспективе =)

Comment: Является ли такая операция присваивания эффективней, чем реализация с поэлементным присваиванием без функции swap? Т.е. мы создаем копию объекта, для которой вызываем swap. Насколько затратна эта операция (создания копии; swap, понятно, дешев)?

Comment: Для простых типов a la встроенные - может, и нет. Для сложных членов, для которых требуется выделение памяти и т.п. - скорее всего одинаково. Если у вас агрегатный класс с "нормальными" :) членами - то может быть, лучше всего написать после объявления оператора присваивания `=default` и не мучиться. Кстати, начиная с С++11 можно воспользоваться семантикой перемещения... Но в общем нетривиальном случае - думаю, этот способ хорош хотя бы тем, что позволяет избежать копипаста...