# Перегрузка оператора + для сложения 2 массивов

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Доброго времени суток! Нужно перегрузить оператор + для сложение двух двумерных массивов. Пыталась перегрузить так, но это вызывает исключение

```
friend Matrix operator +(const Matrix &right, const Matrix &left)
{
    Matrix result (right.n,right.m);

    for (int i = 0; i < right.n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < right.m; j++)
        {
            result.mas[i][j] += right.mas[i][j]+ left.mas[i][j];

        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Как исправить?

**Обновление**

Пока что плохо разбираюсь с конструкторами, но вот, что вышло.

```
Matrix()
{
    n = n;
    m =m;
    mas = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = new int[m];
    }
}
```

Это конструктор по умолчанию, я надеюсь.

И вот еще

```
Matrix (int n, int m) : n(n), m(m)
{
    mas = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = new int[m];
    }
}
```

Comment: какое исключения ?

Comment: @choko  А размеры этих массивов операндов оператора совпадают?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow совпадают

Comment: @ampawd я добавила скрин исключения

Comment: @choko  У меня имеются сомнения на этот счет.

Comment: @choko Либо вы не объявили в классе явно конструктор копирования или копирующий оператор присваивания.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Вы правы, я не объявляла конструктор копирования и копирующий оператор

Comment: покажите пожалуйста код конструктора `Matrix`

Comment: а ещё не имеет смысла через `+=` складывать элементы, достаточно делать `result.mas[i][j] = right.mas[i][j]+ left.mas[i][j];` и это тоже потенциально может вызвать исключение, если через `+=` в случае, например, когда внутренний вектор не инициализирован

Comment: @choko поменяйте `+=` на `=` вот тут `result.mas[i][j] += right.mas[i][j]+ left.mas[i][j];`

Comment: @ampawd я уже увидела эту опечатку и исправила, но исключение все равно осталось

Comment: Во-первых, проблема скорее всего не имеет никакого отношения к приведенному вами коду. Как уже заметили, типичным источником таких проблем является нарушение Правила Трех: неправильно написан конструктор копирования или копирующий оператор присваивания. Во-вторых, если вы что-то "уже исправили", то потрудитесь исправить и код здесь тоже.

Comment: Если можно, совет - имена членов-данных класса пишите с префиксом m_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-хорошему, в конструкторе нужно инициализировать массив. Вы выделили память, теперь там - в массиве - совершенно случайные значения... Это - для конструктора `Matrix (int n, int m)`. В конструкторе `Matrix()` всё вообще весело - **какие** значения вы присваиваете `n` и `m`? Да *те же случайные, что в них и были*.

Даже если исправить конструктор, то при сложении вы не инициализированные значения массива не заменяете, а *прибавляете к ним сумму* элементов, так что там все равно будет мусор...

Ну и обязательно нужно проверять равенство размеров суммируемых массивов! Если не генерацией исключения - то хотя бы `assert`...

Итак, выбросьте конструктор по умолчанию, сделайте один вот такой:

```
Matrix(int n = 1, int m = 1, int value = 0): n(n), m(m)
{
    mas = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = new int[m];
        for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j) mas[i][j] = value;
    }
}
```

B будет он у вас и швец, и жнец (и обычный конструктор, и по умолчанию - создавать массив `1x1`), и даже на дуде игрец - заполнять массив значениями по умолчанию...

Ну, а в операторе `+` напишите не

```
result.mas[i][j] += right.mas[i][j]+ left.mas[i][j];
```

а

```
result.mas[i][j] = right.mas[i][j]+ left.mas[i][j];
```

и добавьте проверку хотя бы `assert(left.n == right.n && left.m == right.m);` или

```
if (left.n != right.n || left.m != right.m)
    throw std::exception("Matrix sizes not matched in operator+()");
```

Ну, и не забудьте, как вам уже писали, копирующий конструктор. Да и оператор присваивания не помешает. О них уже рассказано здесь: [Правильно ли заданы конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания? Как улучшить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/629928/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82/629938#629938)

Comment: Все-таки параметр `value` тут лишний. Никому не нужна матрица, заполненная единицами :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ну да, лучше мусор... Кстати, вы не писали в комитет стандартизации C++, чтоб выбросили соответствующий параметр из конструктора вектора? :)

Comment: `std::vector` - это просто массив переменного размера. Там этот конструктор очень даже в тему. Автор же явно пишет матрицу в математическом смысле - о чем говорит та же операция сложения. Матрица, заполненная единицами, смысла не имеет!

Comment: @PavelMayorov Господи, ну не пишите вы третий параметр, будут нули. Или матрица, заполненная нулями, тоже смысла не имеет? :)

Comment: Конечно же имеет. Это нулевая матрица. Имело бы смысл только это поведение и оставить, а параметр, который никто не будет передавать - убрать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Нулевая матрица, и матрица, заполненная нулями - разные вещи :) Ладно, замнем для ясности и останемся при своих... Я бы на вашем месте скорее ругался на то, что по умолчанию матрица 1x1, а не 0x0 :)